# C++ : How to install Boost in CLion IDE?

Tags: c++

I have already gone through the posts from previous similar questions on StackOverflow. I am still lost.  I am struggling to install boost on CLion. Can someone please explain step by step what needs to be done. Would be forever indebted. Been stuck on this for a while.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you stuck at? Any build errors you can show us?

Comment: The entire process. I do not know where to start. I have downloaded the Boost 1.7.3 files, but i do not know how to proceed. How do i install the package onto my IDE? Sorry if this sounds stupid. I am expected to use boost but we've not been provided any info on how.

Comment: The instructions may depend on your OS and compiler. I mean ubuntu instructions will be different from windows or macOS. On windows mingw instructions could be different from Visual Studio especially because boost does not provide mingw binaries by default.

Comment: I doubt CLion has anything much to do with your problem. Once you manage to install boost on your system, the IDE you use to write your code should be largely irrelevant.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Find out and then follow the instructions given on boost website.

Answer (score 1):

Using a package and dependency manager like [Conan](https://conan.io/) and a build system like CMake (it's CLions' default build system) it's pretty straight forward. This approach is independent of your operating system and you don't need to install boost yourself. The dependency manager will do it for you.

Install Conan on your system.

Create a file named `conanfile.txt` in the root of your project containing

```
[requires]
boost/1.73.0

[generators]
cmake
```

In your main `CMakeLists.txt` you add

```
execute_process(COMMAND conan install ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} --build missing)

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)
```

below `cmake_minimum_required` and `project` but near the beginning.

Add the library to the targets with

```
target_link_libraries(YourTarget PUBLIC CONAN_PKG::boost)
```

An example `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4)

project(YourProjectName CXX)

execute_process(COMMAND conan install ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} --build missing)

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)

add_executable(YourTarget main.cpp)
target_compile_features(YourTarget PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
target_link_libraries(YourTarget PUBLIC CONAN_PKG::boost)
```